# Trying to separate 2 items in a column for listview wpf

Tags: mysql, wpf, listview, asterisk

I am quite a newbie with wpf...any help will be appreciated.
I started a small project with a listview that displays content from MySQL. So far I had no problems except a column that has 2 items in it. I need to **separate each item in its own column.**
It was easy to do with date and time but this one is beyond my skills.

The display of the listview is like that (I can't post images yet):

**Date         |Time |CallerID          |From|To |Duration**

**10 June 2015 |22:45|"alex" <210555555>|101 |201|234**

The `CallerID` column contains the two values with distinct "" and <>. I need to separate as I did with `Date` and `Time`. Thanks for any help.

```
  <ListView x:Name="Datalist" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DS}" Background="White" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="1,0,8,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=calldate,StringFormat={}{0:dd MMMM yyyy}}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=calldate,StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="CallerID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=clid}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="From" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=src}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="To" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=dst}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Duration"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding duration}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

private void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        string cs = @"server=192.168.1.123;userid=alex;
        password=r3s3ll3r;database=asteriskcdrdb";

        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
            {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();

            string stm = "(SELECT * FROM cdr ORDER BY uniqueid DESC LIMIT 1000)";
            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(stm, cs);
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            Datalist.ItemsSource = DS.DefaultView;

            }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());

            }
        finally
            {
            if (rdr != null)
                {
                rdr.Close();
                }

            if (conn != null)
                {
                conn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the collection `DS` that your `ItemsSource` is binding to a collection of a type which you've defined? As in, do you have access to that class?

Comment: Yes, DS is a datatable   DataTable DS = new DataTable(); that i fill with data from mysql database. Thanks for the reply. I should edit the post and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving towards a more complete view model approach. Instead of binding your `ItemsSource` to the `DataTable.DefaultView` directly, you could create a collection of view models that define the presentation logic for each entry. For example, you could define a view model class such as

```c#
public class PhoneCallViewModel
{
  public Date CallDate { get; set; }
  public string CallerId { get; set; }
  // .... Expose properties for each column
}
```

This will open up a lot of options for dealing with your current problem. For example, how could we split up that caller ID string? You could create another view model, such as the following

```c#
public class CallerIDViewModel
{
  public string CallerName { get; set; }
  public string CallerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then the `PhoneCallViewModel` would expose a `CallerIDViewModel` property. In your `OnLoad` method, you would create a collection of these `PhoneCallViewModel` objects (preferably an `ObservableCollection`) and bind the `ItemsSource` to it. Then you could simply replace your existing caller id column in your `ListView` with two new columns. One bound to `CallerID.CallerName`, and the second bound to `CallerID.CallerNumber` (assuming the property on `PhoneCallViewModel` is named `CallerID`).

I've left out the details of splitting the original caller ID as well as instantiating the collection, as those are separate implementation problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will look into it. I thought maybee there was a way to hide what is in "" or <> in listview with a stringformat...or something similar. It sounds good anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a converter and pass your clid to it with a parameter saying if you want the name of the number and it would return you the right one.

It would look like:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="CallerID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=clid, Converter={StaticResource GetCallerIdConverter}, ConverterParameter='Name'}"/>
```

and then the converter:

```
public class GetCallerIdConverter : IValueConverter {

public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
  string callerId = value.toString();
  if (parameter == "Name")
  {
    //your regex to return what's in the double quotes ""
  }
  else
  {
    //your regex to return what's in the < >
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks good also. I will test it and post the solution. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you all for the help, this is a great community!
So, i used a converter as maxime-tremblay-savard suggested.



      class GetCalleridConverter : IValueConverter
            {
                    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
                {
                string callerId = (string)value;
                Regex angleBrackets = new Regex("<[^(>)]*>");
                Regex quotes = new Regex("\"([^\"]*)\"");
                if (parameter.ToString() == "Number")
                    {
                    //your regex to return what's in the double quotes ""

                    Match angled = angleBrackets.Match(callerId);
                    return angled.ToString();
                    }
                else  
                    {
                    Match quot = quotes.Match(callerId);
                    return quot.ToString();
                    }


                }

//And then i binded the item to xaml

.....
  <Page.Resources>
        <valueconverter:GetCalleridConverter x:Key="GetCallerIdConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>
.......
 <GridViewColumn Header="Caller Name" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=clid, Converter={StaticResource GetCallerIdConverter}, ConverterParameter='Name'}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Caller Number" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=clid, Converter={StaticResource GetCallerIdConverter}, ConverterParameter='Number'}"/>

//So, i got two columns with caller Name and Caller Number, only thing left to remove quotes and angle brackets....
```

[image]